# Login form with SQLite in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm having a problem making a loginform with sqlite in C#. this is the code

```
SQLiteConnection connectionstring;
connectionstring = " Data Source = C:\Crystal Management\Crystal Management\bin\Debug\Konaku.db; Version = 3 ";
public void LoadData()
{  
    try
    {
         SQLiteCommand SelectCommand = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT `Username`, `Password` FROM `LoginData` WHERE `Username` = '" + flatTextBox1.Text + "' AND `Password` = '" + flatTextBox2.Text + "'", connectionstring);
         SQLiteDataReader myReader;
         connectionstring.Open();
         myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
         int count = 0;
         while (myReader.Read())
         {
             count = count + 1;
         }
         if (count == 1)
         {
             Base bs = new Base();
             bs.Show();
             this.Hide();
             connectionstring.Close();
         }
         else if (count == 0)
         {
             flatAlertBox1.kind = FlatUI.FlatAlertBox._Kind.Error;
             flatAlertBox1.Text = "data not right";
             connectionstring.Close();

         }
         else
         {

         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex) {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
          connectionstring.Close();
     }
}
```

it is showing error in this line of code

```
connectionstring = " Data Source = C:\\Crystal Management\\Crystal Management\bin\\Debug\\Konaku.db; Version = 3 ";
```

message error is : Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteConnection'

what can I do with this?

Comment: Pass in the connection string into the `SQLiteConnection("connectionString")`.

Comment: just did, and it cant find the file. it shows " File : 'C:\Crystal Management\Crystal Management\bin\Debug\Konaku.db' does not exist. Use ConnectionString parameter New = true to create a new file

EDIT: looks like I missed a \ after bin\\debug. but now when try the code, it shows "unrecognized token " ' "

Comment: Hard coding a path in your code is a secure recipe for failures. What if the destination computer doesn't have that path? Use the app.config to store this information

Comment: I agree with Steve, either you put the path in a web/app.config, or in a separate DB

Comment: @Steve Who's that person who doesnt have a C disk? Also, this i a software for my dad laptop, and I am designing this just for him.

and putting the file in the directory he has

Comment: What do you mean by a C dick?!! lol

Comment: Im really sorry @Steve I mean C directory. this is embarrassing now.

Comment: No worry, it has been fun....

Comment: so, @Steve and SoftEng why am I getting this error "unrecognized token " ' " ?

Comment: A different one of course. I'd bet the query contains a smart quote. The OP should really try to get the program to compile, not ask for help for each individual line. SO is a Q&A site for specific questions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It has been the 10th time I'm trying to compile the program, I searched the entire code, line by line, and there is no single quote. except the SQLiteCommand code.

Comment: Which is why you should post the full error and actually check the line where it occurs. Your *SQL statement* contains a lot of quotes. Or is it an runtime exception? Where? You are combining a raw SQL statement with raw text. If someone typed a single quote in the username or password field you'd get an invalid query

Comment: In fact, if someone typed `';DROP TABLE LoginData;--` you'd lose your table. That's how SQL injection attacks happen. If you have a runtime error, post the *full* exception, as returned by `Exception.ToString()`. This contains the actual line where the problem occured and the call stack that shows where the error occured exactly. I'll bet this runtime error occurs somewhere in SqlCommand.ExecuteReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proper way to query SQL. Always use "using" for disposable class like SQLiteConnection, SQLiteCommand, and SQLiteDataReader. Use parameterized queries to avoid sql injection.

```
public void LoadData()
{
  try
  {
    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Crystal Management\Crystal Management\bin\Debug\Konaku.db;Version=3"))
    {
      conn.Open();
      using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT Username,Password FROM LoginData WHERE Username='@username' AND Password = '@password'", conn))
      {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", flatTextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", flatTextBox2.Text);
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
          var count = 0;
          while (reader.Read())
          {
            count = count + 1;
          }
          if (count == 1)
          {
            Base bs = new Base();
            bs.Show();
            Hide();
          }
          else if (count == 0)
          {
            flatAlertBox1.kind = FlatUI.FlatAlertBox._Kind.Error;
            flatAlertBox1.Text = "data not right";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: found it about 30 minutes ago, but still thanks. this is what I was looking

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

```
sql_con = new SQLiteConnection
    ("Data Source=C:\Crystal Management\Crystal Management\bin\Debug\Konaku.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
```

Comment: got "unrecognized token " ' "

Comment: Backslash must be double backslash "\\"

Comment: The SQL statement contains a smart single quote.

Comment: the only place where a single quote is at sqliteCommand.
SELECT `Username`, `Password` FROM `Login`

Comment: @x... yes, with double backslash shows " unrecognized token ' "

Comment: Probably not here, which line ? Because that charachter is in your SELECT query.